# The actual response returned for a broken image load

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Using the `Image` `onerror` attribute is a widely known practice to detect/handle broken images.

But in my particular case I need to perform different actions based on the HTTP status code (if any), http headers (if any) and the actual response body (if any).

I've gone through the standard, google and just manually through the error object passed into the callback and almost certainly am sure it's not possible to do.

So I just need someone to confirm or refute that with an example.

As a baseline we might use this code:

```
var i = new Image();
i.onerror = function(e) {};
i.src = someUrl;
```

So, is there a way to do what I want or no?

Comment: If the image is from the same domain, or CORS-enabled, you could make an AJAX request for it, and see what headers you get … (although CORS might probably not be implemented by the remote server, if it can't actually find the image.)

Comment: @CBroe it's my server in this case and I see that as a potential workaround, but even then - there is no guarantee the second response will be identical to the original.

Comment: Is there really a need to check for that client-side then? Evaluating the server logs for errors on a regular basis and/or implementing a 404/500/... ErrorDocument that logs/notifies someone not enough? _"there is no guarantee the second response will be identical to the original"_ - is your server generally in a bit of a mood, or why do you expect different results for two subsequent requests by the same client??

Comment: What are those different actions you need to perform, based on the criteria you mentioned?

Comment: @CBroe that's a resource server that *may* generate resources on demand. In some cases I want to trigger generation and await on while it's done, and in some other - just show a broken image. "or why do you expect different results for two subsequent requests by the same clien" --- because the load failure may be caused not only by the "problems" on the server, but also on the client, or inbetween.

Comment: OK, fair enough. But I think the conclusion you already came to might be the correct one. I don’t know of any other way than an AJAX request to get access to the actual HTTP headers (at least not via code running in the context of a web page.)

Comment: Would it perhaps be an option to load the images via AJAX in the first place? As in, if the request is answered successfully, convert it into a Data URI and use that to display the image ... (how smooth that'll work might depend on how big the images are, how many, etc.) At least that could help circumvent the two-requests-possibly-two-different-responses problem.

Comment: @CBroe that sounds interesting!